# Trying to send mail with PHP Mailer and BCC

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using the plugin "PHPMailer-master" to send email to adresses stored in my db.

I collect all adresses in a string:

```
$recipients = "mail@mail.com;mail@mail.com;mail@mail.com"; // OR
$recipients = "mail@mail.com,mail@mail.com,mail@mail.com";
```

Later i set BCC:

```
$mail->addBCC($recipients);
```

I also set my mail to get the mail:

```
$mail->addAddress('my@mail.com');
```

So, i get no errors... but the only mail that is sent is the one to myself.. what can be the problem? How can i search what's wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is how i create my string:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $recipients .= $row['email'] . ";";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add the mails like this. The Documentation for AddBCC looks like this `AddBCC($address, $name = "")`.
I recommend you to use foreach loop or something similar:

```
$recipientsArray = explode(";",$recipients); //The delimiter depends on your string that separated the emails
foreach($recipientsArray as $recipient) {
  $mail->addBCC($recipient);
}
```

**Update (Regarding your update)**

How you create the Array does not matter. The key point is that the PHPMailer function only accepts one BCC per call. If you fetch it, then you can do it like this:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $recipients[] = $row["email"];
}
```

Comment: ok, check my update. I do not need to use explode.. i can collect the mail adresses in array directly by: $stmt->fetchAll();

Comment: Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string. /plugins/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php //Sorry it was my fault i used ->fetchAll();